# Solution to a Functional Equation $g'(x)=\dfrac{g(bx)-g(x)}{(b-1)x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations

What approaches can we take to solve the functional equation,

$g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function, such that,

$$g'(x)=\dfrac{g(bx)-g(x)}{(b-1)x}$$

Where, $b \in \mathbb{R}$ is a constant.

My question arises from trying to solve [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/718166/if-fx-a-int-xx1ftdt-is-constant-then-fx-is-constant-or-fx-ae/719483#719483) question.

Answer (score 1):

If $g(x)$ is an $n$th-order polynomial with $g(0) = 0$, then $$\frac{g(bx)-g(x)}{x}$$ will be a polynomial of order $n-1$.  Conveniently, differentiation of an $n$th-order polynomial also results in a polynomial of order $n-1$.

With this in mind, we try $g(x) = ax^n$.  As it turns out, $ax^n$ is a solution for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$, where $n$ is given implicitly by $$n = \frac{b^n-1}{b-1}.$$  As an example, when $b = -1$, we can have both $n = 0$ and $n = 1$.